# echo date on input control (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, input

I am trying to echo the date from database to input control but the date is not appearing. My input is as follow :

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_out" value="<?php echo isset($itemOutData->date_out) ? set_value('date_out', date('m/d/Y', strtotime($itemOutData->date_out))) : set_value('date_out'); ?>">
```

If I do **inspect** from the browser, the value is `08/16/2017`, but the input control just displaying `mm/dd/yyyy`

**Input control**

[image]

Comment: input control?can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: @MacBooc `set_value` is codeigniter framework helper control

Comment: It must be js part doesn't recognise the value. What you're using to show the calendar?

Comment: @AlexBlex that input is just using normal html input . HTML code has provided datepicker template by using the `type="date"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Html5 date type value format is 'Y-m-d';

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_out" value="<?php echo isset($itemOutData->date_out) ? set_value('date_out', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($itemOutData->date_out))) : set_value('date_out'); ?>">
```